# Error viewing images in gridview that are stored in SQL Server 2008 R2 database

Tags: c#, image, datagridview

Whenever I use to scroll my grid view scroll when it moves to image column which pop up error something like this.

> System.Argument Exception: Parameter is not valid

I couldn't understand the error as I am passing the correct set of parameters.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what u have tried so far?

Comment: I want to display images in grid view that are stored in database.Should I convert this to bytes before displaying **or** should I display path of image instead of actual image ?

Comment: why are u storing images in database? You can store it on local folder.. and that will be the easest task